# How to run EngageOne Correspondent on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

by 3 days we have a new project with this product developed by Pitney Bowes. Never see that before.

I imported EngageOneCorrespondent.war and EngageOne.ear in Eclipse to try to run that inside a Eclipse environement. I've tried whit JBoss EAP 6.2

Sadly, at first startup, this error appears:

```
    16:41:58,239 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."config-framework.jar.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."config-framework.jar.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "config-framework.jar.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.pb.config.BaseConfigAPI with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.config-framework.jar.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/pb/util/i18n/LocaleMessages;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pb.util.i18n.LocaleMessages from [Module "deployment.config-framework.jar.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 15 more
```

that jar is correctly deployed on JBoss ... dont know what to do :(

Comment: It would be wise to edit your question to use correct and full english. It may sound petty, but you'll be taken more seriously, and therefore be more likely to recieve help.

Comment: sorry, my English is terrible, especially in tenses